# Get current URL in UIWebview but it not respond

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I create app to use UIWebview and show log to url if touch in content in UIWebview.
this is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url1 =[NSURL URLWithString:@"MyWebSite"];
    NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];
    [_webView1 loadRequest:request1];
    NSURL *url2 =[NSURL URLWithString:@"MyWebsite2"];
    NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url2];
    [_webView2 loadRequest:request2];//url menu 2
    NSString *currentURL = [_webView1 stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"];
    NSLog(@"%@",currentURL);
}
```

but I touch the content log is not print and change webview log is print (null)
sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get title of a website before you receive data from the URL.

So

- Set your `webview delegate` to `self`

Then in

- `- webViewDidFinishLoad:` to get title